# How to use variable from another table for UNION

Tags: mysql

I have two sql commands I want to combine. I have changed the variables I am actually using in an attempt make it simpler to explain.

I would like to get the name of all fruits and vegetables with the colors that are a favoriteColor of everyone who's age is equal to the given value.

Currently I have these queries split up and I get the favorite color of people with `SELECT favoriteColor FROM people WHERE age = ?` and then I get all the fruits and vegetables where the color matches the favoriteColor of each person.

I get the matching fruits and vegetables like this:

```
SELECT * FROM ((SELECT 1 as type, name FROM fruits WHERE color = ?)
  UNION ALL
               (SELECT 2 as type, name FROM vegetables WHERE color = ?)) results
```

I basically want something like this, but I haven't been able to get it to work and I also do not want to have to run the same SELECT query twice:

```
SELECT * FROM ((SELECT 1 as type, name FROM fruits WHERE color = 
                   (SELECT favoriteColor FROM people WHERE age = ?))
  UNION ALL
               (SELECT 2 as type, name FROM vegetables WHERE color = 
                   (SELECT favoriteColor FROM people WHERE age = ?))) results
```

And I don't mind if I get duplicated fruits and vegetables, I need the duplicates for my situation.

For example:
If there are 2 people who are 30 years old and both of them like the color red, I want to get all fruits and vegetables that are red twice.

If there are 2 people who are 10 years old and one of them likes the color red and the other one also likes the color green, I want to get all fruits and vegetables that are red and green.

Comment: Can people age only have on favourite colour? Sample data and expected output as text would help clarify.

Comment: @P.Salmon people can only have one favorite color, I know it's difficult to understand, it took me a long time to simplify and it still sounds confusing.   Edit: I added some examples at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you thought you had to test the colour in the union since the driver is people. And I have guessed what our output should be.

```
create table people(id int,name varchar(10),colour varchar(1),age int);

insert into fruits values
(1,'a','a'),(2,'b','a'),(3,'b','b'),(4,'b','c');

insert into vegetables values
(1,'t','a'),(2,'t','u'),(3,'v','v'),(4,'v','w');

insert into people values
(1,'aa','a',10),(2,'bb','b',10),(3,'cc','c',10),(4,'dd','c',11);

select p.name,p.age,p.name,s.`type`,s.name,s.colour
from people p
join
(
select 1 as type, name,colour from fruits 
union
select 2 as type, name,colour from vegetables 
) s
on s.colour = p.colour 
where p.age = 10;

+------+------+------+------+------+--------+
| name | age  | name | type | name | colour |
+------+------+------+------+------+--------+
| aa   |   10 | aa   |    2 | t    | a      |
| aa   |   10 | aa   |    1 | b    | a      |
| aa   |   10 | aa   |    1 | a    | a      |
| bb   |   10 | bb   |    1 | b    | b      |
| cc   |   10 | cc   |    1 | b    | c      |
+------+------+------+------+------+--------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, after an hour of testing all the solutions I got this one to work perfectly, cannot thank you enough!

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it as a pair of unions to create one unified dataset, joined to another (then filtered) dataset:

```
SELECT * FROM
  (
    SELECT 1 as type, name, color FROM fruits
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 as type, name, color FROM vegetables
  ) plants pl
  INNER JOIN

  people pe ON pl.color = pe.favoriteColor
WHERE
    pe.age = 30
```

If you want different columns out of fruit and veg, and there might not be a fruit or veg row for a given color:

```
SELECT * FROM
  people pe
  LEFT JOIN fruits f on pe.favoriteColor = f.color
  LEFT JOIN veg v on pe.favoriteColor = f.color
WHERE
    pe.age = 30
```

But bear in mind that multiple fruits or veg of a given color will cause the result set to multiply in duplicate for the other plant, which could become a nightmare to deal with on the front end

Answer (score 0):

i don't know but the simplied version may be

```
SELECT * FROM ((SELECT 1 as type, name, color FROM fruits WHERE color = ?) UNION ALL
           (SELECT 2 as type, name, color FROM vegetables WHERE color = ?)) results

           where results.color= (SELECT favoriteColor FROM people WHERE age = ?)
```

sorry for indentation